# Rename columns in Pandas based on a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping, rename

I have a `pandas DataFrame` and I would like to rename the columns based on another `DataFrame` that I plan to use as dictionary.

For example, the first `DataFrame` is:

```
          AAA   BBB   CCC   DDD
 index   
  1       1     2     3     4
  2       5     6     7     8
```

and the second `DataFrame` that I would like to use as the dictionary:

```
           val1    val2
  index
    1      AAA      A7
    2      BBB      B0
    3      CCC      C3
    4      DDD      D1
```

What I would like to get as result is the following:

```
          A7    B0    C3    D1 
 index   
  1       1     2     3     4
  2       5     6     7     8
```

Initially I thought to reshape the first `DataFrame` to long format, then merge with the dictionary `DataFrame` and then reshape back to wide format. However I think this is quite inefficient, so I would like to use a more efficient way (if one exists). Thank you very much four your help.

Comment: do you just want to rename the columns based on the second dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, this is correct, change the first dataframe column names based on the second dataframe.

Comment: You can also just use this one line:`df1.columns=[df2['val2']]`

Comment: Joe, your code in the comment renames by position, not name, which would rarely be the desired effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can first create `dictionary` from `df2`, then create `Series` from columns of `df1` by [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) which you then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) using `dictionary`:

```
print df1
       AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD
index                    
1        1    2    3    4
2        5    6    7    8

print df2
      val1 val2
index          
1      AAA   A7
2      BBB   B0
3      CCC   C3
4      DDD   D1

d = df2.set_index('val1').to_dict()
print d['val2']
{'AAA': 'A7', 'BBB': 'B0', 'CCC': 'C3', 'DDD': 'D1'}

df1.columns = df1.columns.to_series().map(d['val2'])
print df1
       A7  B0  C3  D1
index                
1       1   2   3   4
2       5   6   7   8
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much again for the reply and the promptness!

Answer (score 50):

[df.rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) has a parameter called `columns` that accepts dictionaries:

```
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df2["val1"], df2["val2"])))
```

Out:

```
    A7  B0  C3  D1
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
```

It returns a new DataFrame. You can either use `inplace=True`, or assign it back to the original DataFrame.

Comment: or yet simpler : df1.rename(columns=dict(df2.values)).

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns=dict(df2.values))
```

Answer (score -4):

You can also just use this one line:

```
df1.columns=[df2['val2']]
```

Output:

```
    A7  B0  C3  D1
0   1   2   3   7
1   5   6   7   8
```

Comment: That is not renaming via dictionary, i.e. Old name => New Name.  Your solution renames the columns by position.