# Rename pandas column based on a dictionary only if the name is in the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, rename

I want to rename the columns in my dataframe, using a the names in a dictionary, but in my case, the dictionaries I have don't represent al the column names, so I want to change only the ones I have in my dictionary.
For example

```
       key1 key2 key3 key4
index
1      val1 val2 val3 val4
2      val5 val6 val7 val8
3      ...
4
5
```

And my dictionary is

```
{'key1': 'name1',
 'key2': 'name2',
 'key4': 'name4'
}
```

what I want to get is

```
       name1 name2 key3 name4
index
1      val1 val2 val3 val4
2      val5 val6 val7 val8
3      ...
4
5
```

so I am trying to do the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531675/rename-columns-in-pandas-based-on-dictionary), but mapping doesn't work because the keys that are not in my dict end as `Nans` in the column names.
Does anyone know how to do this? T-T

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `dict.get` in a list comprehension (note that I named the dictionary `d` here):

```
df.columns = [d.get(k,k) for k in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
      name1 name2  key3 name4
index                        
1      val1  val2  val3  val4
2      val5  val6  val7  val8
```